# PXE Boot menu architecture based

Tags: windows, boot, pxe

Is it possible to hide/unhide PXE boot menu items? We have an x86 boot configuration for TinyCore. This works perfect with PXE boot. Now we want to add a Arm version of PiCore to the PXE menu so we can boot rPi's. For now we can only point to 1 default item in the PXE menu.

PXE menu:

````
 DEFAULT      vesamenu.c32
 PROMPT       0
 NOESCAPE     0
 ALLOWOPTIONS 0
 # Timeout in units of 1/10 s
 TIMEOUT 30
 MENU MARGIN 10
 MENU ROWS 16
 MENU TABMSGROW 21
 MENU TIMEOUTROW 26
 MENU COLOR BORDER  30;44   #20ffffff #00000000 none
 MENU COLOR SCROLLBAR   30;44   #20ffffff #00000000 none
 MENU COLOR TITLE   0   #ffffffff #00000000 none
 MENU COLOR SEL     30;47   #40000000 #20ffffff
 MENU BACKGROUND background.jpg
 MENU TITLE PXE Boot Menu
 
 LABEL wds
 MENU LABEL Windows Deployment Services
 KERNEL pxeboot.0
 
 LABEL abort
 MENU LABEL AbortPXE
 KERNEL abortpxe.0
 
 LABEL local 
 MENU LABEL Boot from Harddisk
 LOCALBOOT 0


LABEL TinyCore NFS
MENU LABEL ^TinyCore NFS
MENU DEFAULT
KERNEL Linux/TinyCore2/vmlinuz tz=Europe/Amsterdam
INITRD Linux/TinyCore2/core.gz nfsmount=192.168.1.1:/mnt/nfs_share/TinyCore
APPEND quiet```
````

Answer (score -1):

There is https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Menu#MENU_HIDE

But I don't think there is anything that can change "on runtime"

With [iPXE](https://ipxe.org) you could use a script that detects platform that adds relevant items, different beast and a bit longer startup stretch, but in the end opens up a bunch of possibilities. (iPXE can also be built for efi ARM)